# String Format wrong format for %

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I want to format an Axis in a Chart. For this i have following line:

```
chart.ChartAreas[series.Name].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format =
  "{0.# " + unit + ";-0.# " + unit + ";0 " + unit + "}";
```

Example for unit = "Joule": `Format = "{0.# Joule;-0.# Joule;0 Joule"}`

It brings me a good result (e.g. 1.5 -> "1.5 Joule", -1.4 -> "-1.4 Joule").

But if `unit = "%"` the values are multiplicated by 100. Means 5 -> "500%", 1.3 -> "130%"... and that's wrong. Also some inputs like " %" (with a variable spaces in the string), "_%", "‰" multiplicate the numbers.

Is there a way to show a percent number and prevent this effect?

Please note that i have to use the Format in this form `Format = "???";` and i don't want to manipulate any DataPoints (like every DataPoint / 100).

Comment: What kind of Chart objects are you using? Excel or something else?

Comment: Did you try `{P0.#}` ?

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart;

Comment: @abhitalks: No, but i tried and `{P0.#}` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put literal characters in quotes to avoid them being interpreted as format codes:

```
chart.ChartAreas[series.Name].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format =
     "{0.# '" + unit + "';-0.# '" + unit + "';0 '" + unit + "'}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the percentage sign.

```
unit = @"\%";
```

or

```
unit = "\\%;
```